# C++ Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением

Tags: c++

Выдаёт ошибку "Выражение должно быть допустимым" в нескольких строках с переменными "can" и "total". Заранее благодарю за ответ!

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    const unsigned char magic[3][3] = { (1, 2, 3), (2, 8, 16), (4, 16, 32) };
    long n, code;
    bool can[3][3];
    double total[1][3][63];
    double answer;
    string filein, fileout;

    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Введите путь, откуда будут браться данные";
    std::cin >> filein;
    std::cout << "Введите путь, куда будут сохраняться данные";
    std::cin >> filein;
    ifstream input(filein);
    if (!input){
        cout << "Файл не открыт\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Все ОК! Файл открыт!\n\n";
        return 1;
    }
    ifstream output(fileout);
    string s;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int u = 1; n <= 3; u++) {
        std::cin >> s;
        int s2 = stoi(s);
        for (int p = 1; s2 <= 5; p++) {
            if (s[p] = 'Y') {
                can[u, p] = true;
                can[u, p] = true;
            }
        }
        }
    code = 0;
    for (int u = 1; u <= 3; ++u) {
        for (int p = 1; p <= 3; ++p) {
            if (can[u, p]); {
                code = code + magic[u, p];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int u = 1; u <= 3; ++u) {
        total[1, u, 0] = 1;
    }
    for (int u = 2; u <= n; ++u) {
        for (int p = 0; p <= 63; ++p) {
            for (int k = 1; k <= 3; ++k) {
                total[u % 2, k, p] = 0;
                for (int l = 1; l <= 3; ++l) {
                    if (magic[k, l] && p != 0);
                    total[u % 2, k, p] = total[u % 2, k, p] + total[1 - u % 2, l, p];
                    total[u % 2, k, p] = total[u % 2, k, p] + total[1 - u % 2, l, p - magic[k, l]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    answer = 0;
    for (int u = 1; u <= 3; ++u) {
        answer = answer + total[n % 2, u, code];
    }
    std::cout << answer << "\n";
}```
````

Comment: В некоторых - это в каких? На глаз вижу две проблемы: в инициализации массива нужны фигурные скобки вместо круглых, и вместо `[a, b]` надо писать `[a][b]`.

Comment: `total[u % 2, k, p]` не правильно... `total[u % 2][k][p]` и т д.

Answer (score 2):

Как вы думаете, что это значит?

```
can[u, p]
```

Нет, это вовсе не элемент в u-й строке и p-м столбце. Читай "оператор запятая".

Правильно писать

```
can[u][p]
```

Ну, и точно так же в других местах...

Заодно после того, как исправите запятую, подумайте — нужна ли тут точка с запятой:

```
if (can[u,p]); {

if (magic[k,l] && p != 0);
```

И еще: здесь точно нужно именно присваивание, а не сравнение?

```
if (s[p] = 'Y') {
```

Comment: Спасибо, исправил некоторые ошибки. На счёт строки if (s[p] = 'Y') {" забыл дописать функцию. Честно говоря не знаю как она звучит в C++, но в паскале upcase.

Comment: Вопрос не в функции, а в том, что `=` — это присваивание, а сравнение — это `==`...

Comment: Нужно именно присваивание

Comment: @VenDeks, нет, не нужно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а можете ответить почему? Мне ещё нужно как я понял вставить здесь функцию toupper до s[p].